# Navegar por Sites Clicando em Botões de Anterior e Proximo

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Gostaria de fazer o WebBrowser navegar por uma lista de sites clicando no botão de Anterior e Próximo para navegar pelos sites.

[image: Print da Form no Visual Studio 2015]

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está muito Genérica Sérgio, vamos por partes.. primeiro já sabe carregar a url pro webbrowser? depois usar os botões next com o array das urls?..etc

Comment: Olha, eu tenho uma noção... webBrowser1.Navigate("www.site.com"); pra navegar mas não tenho ideia de como fazer esse negocio de array xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, aqui vai uma possibilidade, usando apenas coisas básicas.

Crie um *array* no escopo da classe (do `form` no caso), neste *array* vão ficar salvos todos os sites da sua "lista" de sites. E crie, também no escopo da classe, uma variável que vai manter salvo qual é a posição deste array que está sendo acessada no momento.

Vamos assumir que ao abrir o *form*, o `webBroser` irá navegar para o primeiro site da lista, ou seja, o *index* **zero** do *array*.

```
string[] listaSites = new[] { "https://pt.stackoverflow.com", "https://stackoverflow.com" };

int posicaoAtual = 0;
```

Então, nos cliques dos botões você vai validar o seguinte:

1. No botão **`Próximo`**, será capturado o próximo site da lista, com base no que já está sendo mostrado para o usuário (`posicaoAtual`).

   a. Se existir um próximo site na lista (`posicaoAtual` for menor que o último *index* do *array*, ou seja, tamanho do *array* subtraindo 1), o mesmo será acessado.

   b. Se não existir um próximo site (`posicaoAtual` for exatamente o último *index* do *array*) nada irá acontecer.
2. No botão **`Anterior`**, será capturado o site anterior, também com base no que já está sendo mostrado.

   a. Se existir site anterior na lista (se `posicaoAtual` maior que 0), o mesmo será acessado.

   b. Se não existir um site anterior (se `posicaoAtual` for 0), nada irá acontecer.

O código vai ficar basicamente assim

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    string[] listaSites = new[] { "https://pt.stackoverflow.com", "https://stackoverflow.com" };

    int posicaoAtual = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private static void btAnterior_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(posicaoAtual - 1 >= 0)
        {
            posicaoAtual -= 1;
            // (^-) Trocar a posição atual para a anterior
            webBrowser.Navigate(listaSites[posicaoAtual]);
            // (^-) Navegar para o respectivo site
        }
    }

    private static void btProximo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(posicaoAtual + 1 < listaSites.Length)
        {
            posicaoAtual += 1;
            // (^-) Trocar a posição atual para a próxima
            webBrowser.Navigate(listaSites[posicaoAtual]);
            // (^-) Navegar para o respectivo site
        }
    }
}
```